# Limits in the Ideal Carving Equation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am using [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0310086v3.pdf) source to do a mathematics research paper on the ideal carving equation in skiing, however I am having trouble understanding and explaining how these limits work:
[image]

In the first function how do I show that the function tends to infinity as $R$ tends to $0$, where $Rsc$ is a parameter.

The second is a three variable function and I am quite confused at to how this limit is determined. Where $g, α$ and $Rsc$ are parameters.

This is all on page [11](http://www.example.com/)

Any explaining would be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $R \to 0$, $R^2_{SC}/R^2$ becomes huge, right? Subtracting $1$ and then taking the square root still leaves a large number (this is of course only the idea, and not a rigorous argument).

The second one is more subtle. You manipulate the second part of the expression to factor out a $\sqrt{1/R}$ to cancel with the $\sqrt R$ in the first half. In particular,

$$
\sqrt{gR\cos\alpha}\sqrt{\sqrt{\dfrac{R_{SC}^2 - R^2}{R^2}} + \dfrac{R}{R}\tan\alpha\cos\beta} \\
= \sqrt{gR\cos\alpha}\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{R}}\sqrt{\sqrt{R_{SC}^2 - R^2} + R\tan\alpha\cos\beta}\\
= \sqrt{g\cos\alpha}\sqrt{\sqrt{R_{SC}^2 - R^2} + R\tan\alpha\cos\beta}
$$

and now let $R \to 0$.

Comment: Well that was simple, thanks for your help!